# React native debugging error: "Requiring unknown module "RelayProfiler". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager."

Tags: react-native

Created a demo project and this error happens all the time in Chrome dev tools:

**Requiring unknown module "RelayProfiler". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.**
[image]

Comment: Can you show some code? Specifically where you are requiring relay profiler?

Comment: i just created an empty project with init command, I can zip and upload if you want.

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: i switched off stopping on errors. And actually I switched to ionic for the moment, because React is too raw. No Android push yet